# HTML - w3-include-html reading javascript issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am using codepen.io to create a project and in that project, I have created two html pages. The first is called "header.html" and the second is "index.html". I am using "w3-include-html" to include my header.html file in my index.html file. The header.html file uses an external javascript file to return date time to a specific id I created called "time". The problem is when I am in my index.html page, the header gets shown and the code gets run but the document.getElementById function cannot find the id from the external html page used in index.html.

Here is my code:

**header.html**

```
<html>
   <head>
       <script src="scripts/userInfo.js"></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p id ="userName">username</p>
      <p id ="time"></p>
      <p id ="logcount">timeCounter</p>   
      <script>
           dateTime();       
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script> <-used to 
     enable the use of the w3-include-html 
   </head>
   <body>
     <div w3-include-html="header.html"></div> <- refers to my html file and 
       places the assets on the page 

     <script>
        w3.includeHTML(); <--to include the html file
     </script>
     <script src="scripts/userInfo.js"></script> <-- reference to javascript 
                                              file being used by header.html
   </body>
</html>
```

**userInfo.js**

```
var sec =0;
var minute = 0;
var hour = 0;

var timeOutput;

function dateTime(){

  var date = new Date();

  var day = date.toDateString();

  var hours = date.getHours();
  var minutes = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();


  try{
    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = day + " " + hours + ":" + 
    minutes;
  }catch(error){
     alert(error); <- when run on the index.html page I get an error saying 
     that the id "time" could not be found. This does work when running just 
     on the header.html page.
  }

  setTimeout(dateTime,1000);
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This W3 Schools script is not a standard and upon looking at its source code, it relies on XHLHttpRequest objects (AJAX). AJAX requests will only work when the code is requested from a server over HTTP or HTTPS, so make sure when you test this code that you are running it on a server.

In addition, even if you get this working, the included file should not be an entire HTML document. It should just be a fragment that you intend to insert into a larger file. Since you are attempting to inject your `header.html` file into a `div` of `index.html`, you should only inject code that would be valid inside of a `div`, so change `header.html` to this:

```
<p id ="userName">username</p>
<p id ="time"></p>
<p id ="logcount">timeCounter</p>   
<!-- You want the .js reference to come before your
     attempt to use the code in the file and also
     after any elements that the code will refer to.  -->
<script src="scripts/userInfo.js"></script>
<script>dateTime();</script>
```

Comment: I tried doing that, and unfortunately, that did not solve the problem, here is the error I am getting from the index.html page when trying to reference an id from the header.html page: TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: @RW6 See my updated answer. Are you running this code from a server or  testing it locally? Also, just using a plain AJAX call instead of anything from W3 Schools would be much simpler and preferred. W3 Schools is well-known to have out of date and/or flat out wrong information on it.

Comment: I am using the codepen.io environment to test it. And the code runs fine when testing just the header.html page, its just when i am testing the index.html page that the header.html page gets displayed on the screen but the id's from that external file cannot be found in the javascript file.

Comment: @RW6 There wouldn't be any issues running `header.html` because that's not where the AJAX calls are being made. Those are coming from `index.html`. I would bet that CodePen is not a suitable test environment for this code. Again, I would ditch the entire W3.js deal and just make a plain old AJAX call.

Comment: I am pretty new to AJAX so if I wanted to do that how would do this? And a little more information, the only files i can create using codepen.io is javascript, html, and css

Comment: how can we turn this into a local solution without a server?