# Javascript changing element which is being imported from another HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, css, class, getelementbyid

Im trying import some HTML code which i did like the following and it WORKS! Thats not the problem but it has something to do with that. I use a "universal html file" which i then can import into whatever document i like and then it has that certain header. Also i can change the universal code and all the other pages also changes. It saves me a lot of work.

**This is how i import HTML code using some code from W3Schools**

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_html_include.asp

```
<body>
    <div w3-include-html="universalHTML/header.html"></div>
    <script src="universalHTML/includeHTML.js"></script>

    <script>
        includeHTML();
    </script>
<body>
```

The code above works perfect just to be clear.
**Here comes my problem**

In each different page i want it to highlight a certain link *(in the imported header)* so you know which page you are on, for an example pressing on the home link in the header makes the home link red. This is of course the header i imported from the universal html code.

I obviously want to have a link in the header have this red color depending on which page im on. So i cant just change the universal html cause that would change it on all the sites. And thats not the point.

**Im trying to achieve a red color with Javascript by adding a css class to the link which then makes it red.**

**This is how i try to add a class to the imported HTML element from the universal html code**

```
<script>
    var element = document.getElementById("link_home");
    console.log(element);
    element.classList.add("current_link");
 </script>
```

It of course dosnt work and when i print out the "element" variable it says null. So it cant see that this element is there *maybe because its imported?*
So how can i achieve this while still importing the universal HTML. Should i just do it the old fashion way by just copying the same header in each page and changing the class manually or what??

Thanks in advance

-Bjørn

Comment: Have you tried putting this script in a document.ready function?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML - w3-include-html reading javascript issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48601626/html-w3-include-html-reading-javascript-issue)

Comment: Not quite sure what that is but i will check it out right now. Will reply when i tried it out. Thanks!

Comment: To solve your issue, you should wait until that element is available, before you continue and try to add that class.

Comment: Also, W3Schools isn't a standard, I would look to more credible sources such as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web).

Comment: Made it work using    `$( window ).on( "load", function() {  });` from https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/ Thanks alot everyone