JavaScript function not working when called to an include html code file
I have a webpage where I want to include footer from external footer html file using (w3-include). The footer also has its own JavaScript file. Inside the footer, I have a dialog box that pops for users to subscribe. The footer is working alright but the JavaScript function is not working when I click on the subscribe button to display the dialog.
here is the main html file
<body>
 <section class="related">
     <div class="rpst"> 
    --- some text here ----
     </div>
  </section>

  <div w3-include-html="footer.html"></div>

    <script src="subscribeDialog.js"></script>
    <script src="include.js"></script>

   <script>includeHTML();</script>

</body>

Here is the footer.html

<section class="footer">
  
  <div class="box-container">
    
--- footer contents here ----

  </div>

      <div class="column_2">
        <div class="dialog">
           <div class="header">
              <p>Subscribe to our newsletter</p>
              <i class="fas fa-times" id="closeDialog"></i>
          </div>
          <section class="subs">
              <div class="subs-inputBox">
                  <form action="subscribe_submit.php" method="POST" autocomplete="off">
                      <div class="subs-inputBox">
                          <div class="form-group">
                          <input name="subs_email" type="email" required class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="sendmail" value="Send">Submit</button>
                      </div>
                  </form>
              </div>
          </section>
        
        </div> 
    
        <div class="subContainer">
            <h2>Subscribe to our newsletter</h2>
            
            <h1 id="openDialog">subscribe</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  
</div>

</section>

<script src="subscribeDialog.js"></script>

Here is the subscribeDialog.js
let d = document.querySelector(".dialog");
let openSubX = document.querySelector("#openDialog");
let closeSubX = document.querySelector("#closeDialog");

const closeDialog = ()=>{
    d.style.visibility="hidden";
};

openDialog.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    d.style.visibility="visible";
    console.log("working");
});

closeDialog.addEventListener("click", ()=>{
    closeDialog();
    console.log("working");
});


I have been working on this error for some days now but to no avail. Anytime I click on the subscribe button it stays unchanged thus nothing happens, which I want it to open the dialog when click.
I got something similar to my case but still doesn't work at my end.

"the JavaScript function is not working" isn't particularly helpful for debugging? Does it do anything? Are there any errors in your dev console?

https://stackoverflow.com/a/48601664/1599011

what would of course help is to see the function includeHTML(); - since that's the code that "doesn't work"

The html code works fine but it is not responding to the javascript subscribeDialog.js file. @mykaf

Okay - this is my includeHTML() function in the include.js file - @mykaf
